# Have users upload and watch videos on my website?

Tags: video

I'd like to enable users to upload and watch videos on my website.  This is very much like what a site like youtube currently does.  I'm not trying to create another youtube.  The video functionality is complimentary to other, already existing functionality the site has.  I don't mind having the users upload via youtube or another video sharing site.  The videos don't have to be private, but I do need to control the upload process.  Meaning, I'd like the video upload to be one step in a multi-step process.  So for example, let's say that if I was building a job search site (I am not), a user might do the following steps.

1. Register and supply some info about yourself
2. Create a resume with employment history
3. Upload a video about yourself for employers to see
4. Review and activate resume

So, in step #3 the user needs to upload a video.

Do I have any way to integrate with an existing video sharing site, but still retain control over the entire process?  Or do I need to create the uploading, converting to FLV, and playing from scratch myself?

I would like to avoid telling the user to independently go on youtube, post a video, and then tell the site what the URL is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

- [Oct 12, 2009: Direct Uploads Server Migration](http://apiblog.youtube.com/2009/10/direct-uploads-server-migration.html)
- [Developer's Guide: Data API Protocol – Browser-based Uploading](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html)